# Are there any Java 5 VM for embedded environments?

Tags: java, embedded, jvm

for a project that targets embedded systems (such as a NAS) I am looking for an embedded Java VM that would support Java 5 and up. Currently, Java 1.4 is supported by VM like IBM's J9. But since Java 1.4 has reached its end-of-life I would be interested whether there are alternatives available, open source or commercially.

Any idea would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as can be seen on Sun's Java Embeded downloads page:  [Java SE for Embedded Downloads](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/embedded.jsp).  The blurb:

> Sun offers Java SE for Embedded
>   products in both binary and source
>   offerings under an innovative
>   licensing model. Development is free,
>   but royalties are required upon
>   deployment on other than general
>   purpose systems (for details see
>   license). Platforms available for
>   embedded use include not only standard
>   Java SE platforms but also platforms
>   that are exclusive for the embedded
>   market. In all cases, the products
>   offered are fully Java SE compliant --
>   which enables you to reuse any Java
>   code from other platforms or products
>   without having to go through porting,
>   recoding and test cycles.

Comment: As far as I can see Sun's Java Embedded only support Linux-based embedded systems. it would be interesting to see whether there is support for other OS as well. But this helps a lot. Thanks!

Comment: They do have a Java 5 implementation for Windows XP-Embedded listed there.  You might want to look around at other JVM vendors, like IBM or maybe even OpenJDK

Comment: I am actually looking for embedded systems such as home routers, NAS devices etc. Those systems sometimes run some kind of ARM-based Linux distro, sometimes other embedded OS. But thanks. Somehow I missed to look at Sun's own side.